# font size after connecting external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, fonts, display-resolution

I have a dell xps 9570 screen has a 4k resolution,I'm using ubuntu 18.04
Everything was fine until I connected an external monitor. I can't make the two monitors work with font size adequate for each, either I get tiny fonts on my laptop screen and good fonts on my monitor or good fonts on my laptop and huge on my monitor.
I tried running with wayland and setting the scale in laptop to 200% this solves the terminal or ubuntu screens but chrome and icons are still super small.

Can anyone suggest what to do?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to change the resolution for both your external Monitor and your laptop from Settings-> Displays->Resolution ??

Comment: I can downgrade mt screen resolution to HD but I hope that is not the only solution